# How to safely login to private docker registry in gitlab?

Tags: security, docker, passwords, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I know there are secret variables and I tried passing the secret to a bash script. 
When used on a bash script that has `#!/bin/bash -x` the password can be seen in clear text when using the docker login command like this:

```
docker login "$USERNAME" "$PASSWORD" $CONTAINERREGISTRY
```

Is there a way to safely login to a container registry in gitlab-ci?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `before_script` at the beginning of the `gitlab-ci.yml` file or inside each job if you need several authentifications:

```
before_script:
  - echo "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" --password-stdin
```

Where `$CI_REGISTRY_USER` and `CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD` would be secret variables.

And after each script or at the beginning of the whole file:

```
after_script:
    - docker logout
```

I wrote an answer about using Gitlab CI and Docker to build docker images :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50684269/8247069

Comment: I got this message "Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: unauthorized: incorrect username or password".

Answer (score 2):

GitLab provides an array of environment variables when running a job. You'll want to become familiar and use them while developing (running test builds and such) so that you won't need to do anything except set the CI/CD variables in GitLab accordingly (like ENV) and Gitlab will provide most of what you'd want. See [GitLab Environment variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#bash).

Just a minor tweak on what has been suggested previously (combining the GitLab suggested with this one.)

For more information on where/how to use before_script and after_script, see [.gitlab-ci-yml Configuration parameters](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#configuration-parameters) I tend to put my login command as one of the last in my main before_script (not in the stages) and my logout in a final "after_script".

```
before_script:
  - echo "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login "$CI_REGISTRY" -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" --password-stdin;
```

Then futher down your .gitlab-ci.yml...

```
after_script:
  - docker logout;
```

For my local development, I create a .env file that follows a common convention then the following bash snippet will check if the file exists and import the values into your shell. To make my project secure AND friendly, `.env` is ignored, but I maintain a .env.sample with safe example values and I DO include that.

```
if [ -f .env ]; then printf "\n\n::Sourcing .env\n" && set -o allexport; source .env; set +o allexport; fi
```

Here's a mostly complete example:

```
image: docker:19.03.9-dind

stages:
  - buildAndPublish

variables:
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
services:
  - docker:19.03.9-dind

before_script:
  - printf "::GitLab ${CI_BUILD_STAGE} stage starting for ${CI_PROJECT_URL}\n";
  - printf "::JobUrl=${CI_JOB_URL}\n";
  - printf "::CommitRef=${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}\n";
  - printf "::CommitMessage=${CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE}\n\n";
  - printf "::PWD=${PWD}\n\n";
  - echo "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login $CI_REGISTRY -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER --password-stdin;

build-and-publish:
  stage: buildAndPublish
  script:
    - buildImage;
    - publishImage;
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master"' # Run for master, but not otherwise
      when: always
    - when: never

after_script:
  - docker logout registry.gitlab.com;
```