# How to build, push and pull multiple docker containers with Gitlab CI?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a docker-compose file which builds two containers, a node app and a ngnix server. Now I would like to automate the build and run process on the server with the help of Gitlab runners. I am pretty new to CI-related stuff so please excuse my approach:

I would want to create multiple repositories on gitlab.com and have a Dockerfile for each one of these. Do I now have to associate a gitlab-runner instance with each of these projects in order to build the image, push it to a docker repo and let the server pull it from there? And then I would have to somehow push the docker-compose file on the server and compose everything from there.

So my questions are:

1. Am I able to run multiple (2 or 3) gitlab-runner for all of my repos on one server?
2. Do I need a specific or shared runner and what exactly is the difference?
3. Why are all tutorials using self hosted Gitlab instances instead of just using gitlab repos (Is it not possible to use gitlab-runner with gitlab.com repos?)
4. Is it possible to use docker-compose in a gitlab-runner pipeline and just build everything at once?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, you can obviously use GitLab CI/CD features on https://gitlab.com as well as on self hosted GitLab instances. It doesn't change anything, except the host on which you will register your runner:

- https://gitlab.com/ in case you uses GitLab without hosting it
- https://your-custom-domain/ in case you host your own instance of GitLab

You can add as many runners as you want (I think so, and at least I have 5-6 runners per project without problem). You just need to register each of those runners for your project. See [Registering Runners](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/) for that.

As for shared runners versus specific runner, I think you should stick to share runners if you wish to try GitLab CI/CD.

> Shared Runners on GitLab.com run in autoscale mode and are powered by DigitalOcean. Autoscaling means reduced wait times to spin up builds, and isolated VMs for each project, thus maximizing security.
>
> They're free to use for public open source projects and limited to 2000 CI minutes per month per group for private projects. Read about all GitLab.com plans.

You can install your own runners on literraly any machine though, for example your laptotp. You can [deploy it with Docker](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html) for a quick start.

Finally, yes you can use docker-compose in a `gitlab-ci.yml` file if you use `ssh` executor and have `docker-compose` install on your server.
But I recommend using the `docker` executor and use [`docker:dind`](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/) (Docker in Docker) image

> What is Docker in Docker?
>
> Although running Docker inside Docker is generally not recommended, there are > some legitimate use cases, such as development of Docker itself.

Here is an example usage, without `docker-compose` though:

```
image: docker:latest

services:
  - name: docker:dind
    command: ["--experimental"]


before_script:
  - apk add --no-cache py-pip      # <-- add python package install pip
  - pip install docker-compose     # <--- add docker-compose 
  - echo "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" --password-stdin    # <---- Login to your registry

build-master:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build --squash --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_USER"/"$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE":latest .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_USER"/"$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE":latest
  only:
    - master

build-dev:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build --squash --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_USER"/"$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE":"$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_USER"/"$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE":"$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
  except:
    - master
```

As you can see, I build the Docker image, tag it, then push it to my Docker registry, but you could push to any registry. And of course you could use docker-compose at any time in a `script` declaration

My Git repository looks like :

```
/my_repo
|---- .gitignore    
|---- .gitlab-ci.yml    
|---- Dockerfile    
|---- README.md
```

And the config.toml of my runner looks like:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "4Gb digital ocean vps"
  url = "https://gitlab.com"
  token = "efnrong44d77a5d40f74fc2ba84d8"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:dind"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
```

You can take a look at https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html for more information about Runner configuration.

> Note : All the variables used here are *secret variables*. See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/ for explanations

I hope it answers your questions

Comment: Wow, thank you for the elaborated answer! That is incredibly helpful. One follow up question though: How would you introduce docker-compose into the mix? Would you implement separate build jobs for each repo and then do a docker-compose in a own repo or is this bad practice? I don't think that I fully understand the role of the gitlab runner. Does the runner just execute the commands on the server on which it is running? Does this runner also "pull" the repository onto the server? I did a first try to build my server but I can't reach it over the ip address of the server. Anyways, thank you.

Comment: Since you can use the `build` keyword when declaring a service in a docker-compose I don't see the benefit in building docker images in separates steps.
The only use case I see where you want to build is when you want to push to docker registry like I did in the example. And even so, why can't you build all images in same steps ? I'm not a devops expert so I can't tell you what would be a bad habit sorry

Comment: And concerning the runners, I only use runners with `docker` executor , you can see available executors on this link : https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/ 
Moreover, you should not install your runners on the same host where GitLab is installed.
That being said, if you deploy GitLab with docker and have enough resources on your server, you can also deploy runners with Docker.

Comment: Ok thank you so much. This helps me to understand the bigger picture way better. I think I will try to figure out how to execute a docker build step with the shell executor first and then introduce the orchestration with docker-compose and dind. Thank you!