# Docker not working in gitlab runner, what could be the problem?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

When I try to run my `gitlab-ci.yml`, I get the following error:

> /bin/bash: line 73: docker: command not found

On my server the `docker` command works as root and gitlab is also executing as root.

What could be the problem here?

Here is my `.yml` file:

```
stages:
  - deploy
  - cleanup

before_script:
  - whoami
  - docker login -u "gitlab-ci-token" -p "$CI_BUILD_TOKEN" "$CI_REGISTRY"
```

Comment: What type of runner do you use?

Comment: I followed this tutorial: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-manually.html

Comment: Its about installation, but what type did you choose? Shell executor, docker or etc?

Comment: If you dont know, it could be difficult for you to setup `docker-in-docker` because it requires more deep understanding of setup process

Comment: I choose shell when registering the runner

Comment: What should i've used?

Comment: Take a look at my answer if you want to use Docker executor. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50684269/7786148

Answer (score 0):

You can verify these 3 steps:

1. Is **Docker Engine** installed on server
2. Is the **gitlab-runner user** added to docker group
3. Has the gitlab-runner access to Docker

Follow the official page for more information: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html

Answer (score 0):

Your `gitlab-ci.yml`  looks incomplete. Try something like this:

```
stages:
  - build

build-docker:
  stage: build
  script:
     - whoami
     - docker login -u "gitlab-ci-token" -p "$CI_BUILD_TOKEN" "$CI_REGISTRY"
```

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding I have more stages after the before_script

Comment: just copied this since it fails there

Comment: Ok well whats the output of your `whoami` command? Chances are that user can't see the docker executable.

Comment: the output is root. Thanks for your help I'm trying everything now but I'm somehow stuck