# How to pull from multiple private registries with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci

I've attempted to pull two images from two different projects registries (gitlab container registry). All that in a `docker-compose.yml` file.

How can I configure my `gitlab-ci.yml` or configure variables (whatever works) in order to pull my images properly without any access problems ?

I have found a solution using `docker login` with a *deploy token* to have read-only access to my project registry. The problem is that works if I had only one image to pull : [How to build, push and pull multiple docker containers with gitlab ci?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50683869/how-to-build-push-and-pull-multiple-docker-containers-with-gitlab-ci/50684269?noredirect=1#comment88403258_50684269)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `docker login` multiple times before running `docker-compose`, one for each registry, and they will stack.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @CCH, just complete by :
In my case I push in registry server with **tag v3.0**
and my docker-compose.yml try to pull on production server with **tag v3**
so I run :

```sh
docker tag registry.server.tdl/my-username/my-project/my-registry-name:v3.0 registry.server.tdl/my-username/my-project/my-registry-name:v3
```

to add tag used in my docker-compose.yml