# How to pull docker image from private docker repository in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-registry, docker-repository

How can I add the docker hub credentials in `docker-compose.yml` and pull the private image?

I want to pull 2 images from 2 different private repositories?

Comment: With `docker login` you shouldnt have problems

Comment: Thank you. But I want to pull images from 2 different private repositories in the same docker-compose file.Is that possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pull from multiple private registries with docker-compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56066235/how-to-pull-from-multiple-private-registries-with-docker-compose)

Comment: Thanks Marius! That is exactly what I was looking for.You saved my day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To push to or pull from private registry, you just need to add the registry’s location to the repository name. It will look like `my.registry.address:port/repositoryname`

On a fresh build it looks as follows

```
docker push localhost.localdomain:5000/ubuntu
Username (): user
Password:
Email (): user@pass.com
```

Then you can use docker login multiple times before running docker-compose, one for each registry, and they will stack.

Comment: Thanks Marius. But I want to pull images from 2 different private repositories in the same docker-compose file.Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use docker login before invoking docker-compose:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/

You would  do something like this

```
services:
  s1:
    image: repo.foo.com/s1

  s2:
    image: repo.bar.com/s2
```

You would login once and Docker would remember your credentials:

```
docker login -u user1 -p pass1 https://repo.foo.com
docker login -u user2 -p pass2 https://repo.bar.com
```

and then you would run docker-compose as many times as you need.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. But I want to pull images from 2 different private repositories in the same docker-compose file.Is that possible?